# How does PhpQuery work? Trying to get the value of <title> tag

Tags: php, tags, title, phpquery

I'm new to [phpQuery](http://code.google.com/p/phpquery/). I need to achieve the simple task of getting the content of the HTML TITLE tag of a webpage. In this case I'm trying to get the title content of "Yahoo!" that should be "Yahoo!".

I'm doing this with phpQuery, but it is now working

```
// Testing phpQuery
$result = phpQuery::newDocumentFile($scraps['Scrap_yahoo']->getPage('http://www.yahoo.com','','off'))
            ->find('title');
echo $result->text();
```

Can someone give me a clue on how to achieve this?

Best Regards,

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think the problem might be your phpQuery invocation with `::newDocumentFile()`. This function needs a filename (not sure if an URL works), but I suspect your `->getPage()` actually fetches the file already. If so, then use the normal `::newDocument()` like so:

```
$html = file_get_contents("http://www.yahoo.com/");
$pq = phpQuery::newDocument($html);
print $pq->find("title")->text();
```

Works for me.