# Content of a div inside a php variable

Tags: php, jquery

I have a lot of php included pages inside a template.

`<h1>` tag is also inside an included page, but I need to change them dynamically:

```
<div id='xnavact'>abc</div>
```

js

```
var a = $('#xnavact').html();
$('h1').html(a);
```

This works but I've heard that Google Search does not include changed content via javascript.

Am I right about this, and how could I make the same thing using php?
Something like:

```
<h1><?php echo $content_of_xnavact ?></h1>
```

But how to get content of a div inside a php variable?

Comment: Why do you need change the content of `h1`? What is wrong with echoing it directly when you echo your `h1` element?

Comment: @HieuLe, I need this value to place on many other places (sidebar, footer...).

Comment: Print them all (main content, sidebar, footer) using PHP?

Comment: @josephting, maybe it's complicated to explain my idea about site configuration, but the only question is `how to get content of a div inside a php variable?`

Comment: @HieuLe, how can I do this? Could you please write a php equivalent for `var a = $('#xnavact').html();`

Comment: Are you perhaps looking for something like jQuery in PHP? See [phpquery](https://code.google.com/p/phpquery/)

Comment: @josephting, I'm just looking for a php way to say: `variable x = content of a specific div`. Like in js - `var a = $('#xnavact').html();`

Comment: It depends where that "abc" comes from. If it's from a variable, you can just print that. Else, you will need something like [phpquery](https://code.google.com/p/phpquery/) to help you select `#xnavact` in PHP. See [phpquery example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4595995/685326).

Comment: @josephting, is it possible that there is no way to do such a simple task using pure php? Must I really learn a new language or plugin for that?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/51148/discussion-between-josephting-and-bonaca)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can parse your HTML content in PHP with some packages like [Symfony 2 Dom Crawler](http://symfony.com/doc/master/components/dom_crawler.html).

If your just want to use a value many time through your script, I think you should consider saving this value in a variable and use it instead of store the whole HTML elements in a static file and use any parser.

An example of using Dom Crawler library for you:

```
use Symfony\Component\DomCrawler\Crawler;
use Symfony\Component\CssSelector\CssSelector;

CssSelector::disableHtmlExtension();

function getInnerHtml( $node ) {
    $innerHTML= '';
    $children = $node->childNodes;
    foreach ($children as $child) {
        $innerHTML .= $child->ownerDocument->saveHtml( $child );
    } 
    return $innerHTML;
} 

$html = <<<'HTML'
<div>
    <div>foo</div>
    <div id="xnavact"><span>bar</span></div>
</div>
HTML;

$crawler = new Crawler($html);

$crawler = $crawler->filter('#xnavact');

foreach ($crawler as $domElement) {
    print getInnerHtml($domElement); //result: <span>bar</span>
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [preg_replace](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php) or I don't understand your question correctly

Comment: I can't believe that the question is not clear. I'm just looking for a php way to say: `variable x = content of a specific div`. Like in js - `var a = $('#xnavact').html();`